# Termo "vivo" como afirmação está correto?

Tags: verbos, uso-de-palavras, gerúndios

Algumas vezes as pessoas usam a palavra "vivo" para afirmar que "sempre" estão fazendo alguma coisa, por exemplo:

- Eu vivo fazendo gracinhas sem graça!
- Fulano vive brigando com Fulana!

No contexto das frases acima podemos entender que a palavra "vivo" pode ser substituída por "sempre está", por exemplo:

- Eu sempre estou fazendo gracinhas sem graça!
- Fulano sempre está brigando com Fulana!

Os termos usando "vivo" está correto? É adequado usar essa expressão? Já que "vivo" também pode ser considerado como "viver" de "morar" em algum lugar.

Comment: Acho que não se usa muito em Portugal o "vivo". mas deixa ver o que dizem os outros Portugueses que parece que eu vivo num Portugal diferente ;)

Comment: @JorgeB. No Brasil tb não se usa muito. Mas de vez em quando aparece alguém falando assim...

Comment: Pessoalmente, eu vivo usando a palavra "vivo" pra deixar claro que vivo (sempre estou) fazendo algo. :-P

Comment: É informalmente usado, no estado de St. Catarina do Brasil, é comum alguém lhe dar uma informação usando uma expressão muito parecida: "Segue reto toda vida, quando chegar no semáforo vire a esquerda" segue reto toda vida aqui nesse link http://clickcatarina.com/segue-reto-toda-vida-nao-tem/

Comment: como gramática é correto, como semântica é regionalismo, em um texto formal ou texto onde o trivial é o apego pela norma culta então não seria adequado.

Comment: @JorgeB. Neste aspeto vivemos no mesmo país. Mas mesmo não ouvindo a expressão aqui, acho-a perfeitamente gramatical, lógica, e muito expressiva. Mas usamos coisa parecidas: _eles vivem às turras, viver na pobreza, viver com dificuldades_. O uso de _viver_ nestes exemplos não é assim tão diferente do uso em _viver fazendo isto ou aquilo_.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Para mim, a questão não é se "viver" nesse sentido seria correto ou não, mas sim se esse tipo de uso é adequado em determinados contextos linguísticos. É importante notar que não há erros gramaticais nas frases acima; a questão é puramente *semântica*.

Parece lógico ver esse uso de "viver" como uma extensão figurada do sentido original da palavra: "viver a vida". Assim, "eu vivo fazendo gracinhas" poderia vir simplesmente de "eu passo a minha vida a fazer gracinhas". Com o passar do tempo, a fórmula poderia ter se tornado mais e mais normal, passando a ser um sentido diferente de "viver". Acho que processos similares devem ter ocorrido com verbos como "andar" e "ficar":

> Eu ando brigando muito com ela.
>
> Fiquei muito triste ontem.

Não acho o fato de "viver" ter outros sentidos seja um problema, visto que em nenhuma dessas frases há ambiguidade e dificuldade de compreensão. Note que "viver", além de significar "morar", tem o sentido primário de "viver a vida"; e certamente não vamos discutir que "viver" não pode ser usado como "morar" só porque tem outro sentido.

Por outro lado, esse uso de "viver" me parece mais coloquial. Dependendo do grau de formalidade do texto e do contexto, pode ser mais adequado substituí-lo por outra construção equivalente:

> Fulano sempre briga com Fulana.
>
> Vou à feira todos os dias.

Comment: Poderíamos ter a tag "Semantica". ;) Realmente, nem lembrei dos casos do "andar" e "ficar"...

Comment: Subscrevo esta resposta. Nem sequer a acharia deslocada num contexto formal. Mas se calhar, sendo de Portugal onde ela não se usa, falta-me a sensibilidade para avaliar a maneira como ela é percebida no Brasil.

Comment: @Jacinto Sou brasileiro e também subscrevo a resposta :) Esses usos figurados de "viver" e "andar" soam perfeitamente naturais.

Comment: Não há nenhuma restrição formal para este uso de viver.

Answer (score 3):

viver fazendo algo

Ele **vive** se queixando. = Ele **não para de** se queixar.

ou seja: viver aqui significa: não parar de fazer algo ou passar a vida fazendo x.

Priberam:

3. **Passar a vida de tal ou tal maneira.** [se queixando, por exemplo]

"viver", in Dicionário Priberam da Língua Portuguesa [em linha], 2008-2021, https://dicionario.priberam.org/viver [consultado em 05-02-2022].

Comment: ou mesmo: Ele passa a vida a queixar-se